# unresolved identifier - for in loop logic

Tags: swift, swift3

This is a sort from bottom to top. While looping the iteration is substituted with the lowest number in the array and this continues all the way to the end.

As you can see I'm refactoring to use stride. Unfortunately `var lowest = firstIndex` is giving me some troubles.

I should be able to complete this function using stride right? I believe I should be using `stride: to` instead of `stride: through`. Thanks to Tim for that tip.

```
func selOrganize(myList: Array<Int>) -> Array<Int> { 1

    var extract = myList

    for firstIndex in 0..<extract.count {

        var lowest = firstIndex

        for var secondIndex = firstIndex + 1; secondIndex < extract.count; secondIndex++ {

            if extract[lowest] > extract[secondIndex] {
                lowest = secondIndex
    }
        }

        if firstIndex != lowest {
            swap(&extract[firstIndex], &extract[lowest])
        }   
    }
    return extract 
}
```

Updated syntax

```
func selOrganize(myList: Array<Int>) -> Array<Int> {

var extract = myList

    // var lowest = firstIndex

    // Do I need 'key'? Should I declare 'lowest' as a variable here?
    // If I do use it here I get a "'lowest' is unmutable because it's a let" error
    for (firstIndex, key) in extract.enumerate() {

        // < > stride uses 'to' and  <= >= stride uses through
        for secondIndex in (firstIndex).stride(to: 0, by: +1) {  

            if extract[lowest] > extract[secondIndex] {
                lowest = secondIndex
            }
        }

    if firstIndex != lowest {
        swap(&extract[firstIndex], &extract[lowest])
    }

}

return extract
}
```

Comment: `a.stride(to: b, by: +1)` includes the same numbers as `a..<b`. Did you mean `0.stride(to: firstIndex, by: 1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work like this:

```
func selOrganize(myList: Array<Int>) -> Array<Int> {

    var extract = myList

    // Accessing indices is simpler than calling enumerate, and
    // the function only needs access to the indices, not the 
    // values of the enumeration:
    for firstIndex in extract.indices {

        // lowest needs to be defined inside this loop if you 
        // are going to initialize it using firstIndex 
        // because firstIndex isn't defined outside the loop.
        var lowest = firstIndex

        // You need to stride from the firstIndex to the end of the
        // array, so the call to stride should look like this:
        for secondIndex in firstIndex.stride(to: extract.count, by: 1) {  

            if extract[lowest] > extract[secondIndex] {
                lowest = secondIndex
            }
        }

        if firstIndex != lowest {
            swap(&extract[firstIndex], &extract[lowest])
        }
    }

    return extract
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work. I plugged in numbers in a playground. Btw, The original print was `print("showing \(extract[lowest]) and \(extract[secondIndex])")` but xcode says `"Use of unresolved identifier 'secondIndex'" ` How is that possible when secondIndex is there?

Comment: `secondIndex` is only defined inside the `for-in` loop. Were you calling print outside of that loop?

Comment: Probably. It works now. I really need to study more. I feel so dense. Maybe I'm just tired. Thanks so much. I am close to finishing my assignment. Btw, how do I know if I should use `stride` vs standard `for i in start..<end`?

Answer (score 1):

`Stride` is not needed, you can do that with standard `for i in start..<end` syntax

```
func selOrganize(myList: Array<Int>) -> Array<Int> {

  var extract = myList

  for firstIndex in 0..<extract.count {
  var lowest = firstIndex
    for secondIndex in (firstIndex + 1)..<extract.count {
      if extract[lowest] > extract[secondIndex] {
        lowest = secondIndex
      }
    }

    if firstIndex != lowest {
      swap(&extract[firstIndex], &extract[lowest])
    }
  }
  return extract
}
```

But actually you can do the same in one line

```
let sortedList = myList.sort{$0 < $1}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have copied your answer into my notes because it's actually the more "orthodox" version. I marked Roman's answer as correct because it mirrors what I've been using thus far. I think I used stride too often in my project so I will use yours when I can. Unfortunately I'm not quite sure when I should and shouldn't use stride.

Comment: I find `stride` most useful when incrementing by more than 1 index per stride. If you are just incrementing 1 index it is no different than using a `for-in` loop.